# Client send Clear-Text Password to Freeradius

Tags: ldap, freeradius

I configured freeradius which use ldap as a backend database.(in ldap, i stored password in ssha)
Because ldap does not support mschap, I Use eap-ttls with pap for authentication.
In freeradius server, when I run freeradius in debug mode, I see username and password of client in cleartext.[freeradius output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glQtc.png)

so, as I said before, because I use ldap as a backend database, I can't use mschap (which is the only secure way I know for client to send his password). I just want to know is there another way to send password that is not visible in output of freeradius?

I Found this options in windows, but I don't know if they are useful for my case or not.
[windows interface configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpRMZ.png)

Thanks.